# Is this a contradiction in Schwinger's measurement algebra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In Julian Schwinger's book *Quantum Mechanics: Symbolism of Atomic Measurements*, pg.33, he says that the process where nothing is measured (represented by the unity symbol $1$) is equal to the process where a physical variable $A$ is measured and every possible result is accepted. This is called the completeness relationship.

But doesn't this contradict quantum mechanics? If the variable $A$ is measured, the state of the system is changed, which is not the case where nothing gets measured. How can these processes be the same algebraically?

He then seems to walk back on this statement on pages 44-45, where he discusses that the probability of measuring a phyisical variable after having measured a previous one is not the same as the case where nothing was measured beforehand.

Comment: Suppose there is only two possible values for a given variable, then after several measurement, you would get all the possible values, then you would say you have measured the variable and found only two different values for it. Now if you measure nothing, identify operator 1, then you would say  you have got all the results with the respective probabilities, two results with different probabilities. Then that would be a completeness relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be a contradiction because it's an imprecise *colloquial* statement rather than a precise mathematical statement.  One way of understanding what he means is that the device that "measures" the physical observable $A$ associated with the operator $\hat{A}$ can't distinguish between the different possible measurement outcomes. In this case, the state is "projected" onto the subspace spanned by all of the eigenvectors, but this is just the identity operation.

To be a little more clear, let's imagine a three-state system and an observable $\hat{A}$ (assumed non-degenerate) represented in spectral form as
$$
\hat{A} = a_1\lvert 1\rangle\langle 1 \rvert
+a_2\lvert 2\rangle\langle 2 \rvert
+a_3\lvert 3\rangle\langle 3 \rvert\,.
$$
A precise (sharp?) measurement of this observable returns one of the three eigenvalues $a_j$ as the outcome, and the corresponding post-measurement state is the corresponding $\lvert j \rangle$. Now, imagine a case where the device is imprecise in just such a way that it can't distinguish between $a_2$ and $a_3$. Then a "measurement" of $A$ returns either $a_1$ or $a_2$-or-$a_3$. If the pre-measurement state is
$$
\lvert\psi_{\textrm{pre}}\rangle = \alpha_1\lvert 1\rangle
+\alpha_2\lvert 2\rangle
+\alpha_3\lvert 3\rangle\,,
$$
then the possible post-measurement states are
$$
\lvert\psi_{\textrm{post}}\rangle = \lvert 1 \rangle
$$
or
$$
\lvert\psi_{\textrm{post}}\rangle = \mathcal{N}(\alpha_2\lvert 2\rangle
+\alpha_3\lvert 3\rangle)\,,
$$
respectively, where $\mathcal{N}$ is a normalization factor. In the second case, we have projected the state onto the subspace spanned by the "degenerate" eigenvectors 2 and 3 (where by *degenerate* here we mean that the detector can't distinguish the two eigenvalues; see Note 1 below).

Finally, imagine that the detector is *very* imprecise and therefore can't distinguish between any of the three values. Then the result of the measurement is $a_1$-or-$a_2$-or-$a_3$, and the post-measurement state is therefore the projection on the subspace spanned by all three eigenvectors, but this is just the entire space, and so the post-measurement state is identical to the pre-measurement state. This "measurement" is the same as a measurement of the identity observable.

---

Notes

1. Really, in the "imprecise" measurement schemes described above, we're really no longer strictly speaking measuring the observable $A$.  We're actually measuring some other *related* observable.  For instance, if $a_1$ is non-zero, we could construct the operator
   $$
   \hat{A}_1 = a_1\lvert 1\rangle\langle 1 \rvert
   +0\lvert 2\rangle\langle 2 \rvert
   +0\lvert 3\rangle\langle 3 \rvert\,,
   $$
   where the outcomes are $a_1$ or 0, and the 0 corresponds to getting $a_2$-or-$a_3$. Still, the above is what Schwinger *means*, although the imprecision of language is perhaps a little annoying.
2. This "smearing-out" or "imprecision" of the measurement device is only one possible way that a detector can be imprecise.  For instance, the device can be imprecise in such a way that it decoheres the state somewhat.  This is moot in this case because what Schwinger means is what I've described above, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't lying to OP by omission.